# Creating new class object without assignment . Why useful?

Tags: frame

My Question is simple i think:

What is the difference between writing :

```
MainFrame MF = new MainFrame();
```

**and**

```
new MainFrame();
```

Is this something like more pro? I mean for the reason why i do not need to use the MainFrame object .... only to create it for getting into that class??

Iam confused ...

I hava a database , and  some frames that i  want to show on screen. Something Like a login button ... and i show a trick of this way for creating an new object of the class..

Comment: Depends on the programming language, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly...

When you do assign the 'new MainFrame()' to he object MF probably you open a connection to you MainFrame. This will save resources because you keep one connection open instead of one per call.

If you just want to call one function and you will never call it again you can do it directly like:

```
(new MainFrame()).getData()
```

But this code does exactly the same as:

```
MainFrame MF = new MainFrame();
MF.getData();
```